# Does git add --all delete things permanently or copy changes over to other branches

Tags: git

I'm pretty sure I'm crazy, but I just need to check. My general flow is

```
git add --all
git commit -m "somethin' somethin'"
```

If I do this, and some files marked for deletion are commited, I can still recover them by reverting an old commit right?

Also, do commits ever make changes to branches other than the one currently checked out?

Comment: "I can still recover them by reverting an old commit right?" Yes. If not, that would be the worst version control system in the world.

Comment: Thank you! Just wanted to make sure, that that was in fact a stupid question : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the first question is yes.

And to the second: a commit in a branch will take effect on another branch only if you merge them.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much! That's totally intuitive, just wanted to make sure.